# how to automatically store the value of a simple flag into a variable?

Tags: boost-program-options

The boost option parser allows one to assign a variable to store the option value, instead of using the `so_long["typing"].as<bool>()` way:

```
bool flag_value;
entries.add_options()
("flag", value<bool>(&flag_value), "a simple flag value");
......
cout<<"flag value is: "<<flag_value<<endl;
```

However, the above option declaration does not create a simple flag option. It actually requires you to enter something as the value (--flag true|false|on|off|yes|no|1|0), which is not what I want.

So, is there any way store the result inside a boolean value, and still keep the option as a simple flag?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To have an option with no value (passing means it is set `true`) you should create it like [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/program_options/overview.html):

```
options_description desc;
desc.add_options()
    ("help", "produce help message")
```

To use notifier for such an option you can use the [following type](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost/program_options/bool_switch.html) as semantics:

```
boost::program_options::bool_switch()
```

it can have `true` or `false` values and no value can be explicitly taken for this option from the command line. If the option is passed then the value is `true`. If not passed - the value is `false`.

Comment: Maybe the downvoter thought you [duplicated another answer of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7277180/591064) ? Here is a +1 to even it out, your answer helped me.