# How to use boost::program_options to accept an optional flag?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

I need to implement an optional flag, say `-f`/`--flag`. Since this is a flag, there is no value associated. In my code I only need to know whether the flag was set or not. What's the proper way to do this using boost::program_options?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [boost-program-options: notifier for options with no value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174781/boost-program-options-notifier-for-options-with-no-value)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

A convenient way to do this is with the `bool_switch` functionality:

```
bool flag = false;

namespace po = boost::program_options;

po::options_description desc("options");

desc.add_options()
  ("flag,f", po::bool_switch(&flag), "description");
po::variables_map vm;
//store & notify

if (flag) {
  // do stuff
}
```

This is safer than manually checking for the string (string only used once in whole definition).

Comment: Centos 7.4, boost 1.53, aarch64. flag is always false, vm.count("flag") is always 1 despite any options change.The method below without bool_switch is correctly working with vm.count.

Comment: The option below will accept a parameter.  For example the command line "... -f 42" will take '42' as a value.  The 42 could represent some other positional.  See: [bool_switch always true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32150230/boost-program-options-bool-always-true).

Answer (score 11):

Use it as usual but without any value:

```
boost::program_options::options_description od("allowed options");
od.add_options()
    ("flag,f", "description");

po::variables_map vm;
// store/ notify vm
if (vm.count("flag")) {
    // flag is set
}
```

See the [Getting Started](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/program_options/tutorial.html#id-1.3.32.4.3) option **help** as an example.