# Boost Program Options bool always True

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

With program options, I am checking valid combinations of arguments. But for some reason, gpu argument is a bool and it is always true regardless if I set it to false on the command line. Is there a way that gpu option can be false if I specified it on the command line? I want to be able to make a bool variable that represents if the option on the command line was used.

Also I couldn't find any documentation on count() for variables_map. Is it a std::map function?

Partial Code:

```
namespace po = boost::program_options;
po::options_description desc("Allowed Options");
desc.add_options()
  ("help,h", "Produce help message")
  ("remove_database,r",po::value<std::vector<std::string>>
    (&remove_database),
    "Remove a pre-built database, provide a name(s) of the database")
  ("gpu,u", po::bool_switch()->default_value(false),
    "Use GPU? Only for specific algorithms");

po::variables_map vm;
po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc,argv,desc),vm);
po::notify(vm);

//Processing Cmd Args
bool help           = vm.count("help");
bool remove         = vm.count("remove_database");
bool gpu            = vm.count("gpu");

test(help,"help");
test(remove, "remove");
test(gpu, "gpu");

.....
void test(bool var1, std::string var2){
  if(var1)
    std::cout << var2 << " is active " << std::endl;
 else
    std::cout << var2 << " is not active " << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
$./a.out -r xx -u off
remove is active 
gpu is active
$./a.out -r xx -u false
remove is active 
gpu is active
```

Comment: `bool_switch` docs: "Works the same way as the 'value<bool>' function, but the created value_semantic won't accept any explicit value. So, if the option is present on the command line, the value will be 'true'."

Answer (score 7):

You're using a `bool_switch`. By default, the option will be `false` like you specified with `->default_value(false)`. Since it's a switch, the mere presence of `-u` or `--gpu` when you run the executable will turn the switch to `true`. It doesn't matter what you put after it.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28133253/2297365) for more usage details.

Answer (score 4):

It seems(*) count() is always 1 for a bool_switch.
Hence one should not use:

```
bool help           = vm.count("help");
```

But instead use:

```
bool help           = vm["help"].as<bool>();
```

Or for "safety"(*):

```
bool help           = vm.count("help") ? vm["help"].as<bool>() : false;
```

(*) Delving into the documentation should tell exactly what is the exact and certain way to do things.

Answer (score 3):

Although not directly answer what OP has asked, I think this is an important note. According to the boost program_options spec [spec](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost/program_options/bool_switch.html), no matter what your default value is, when you specify the option from commandline it always turns the switch to `true`

So if you use `default_value(true)` for `bool_switch()`, you can't really turn it off...